# How do I do a reverse removal of an association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have two models - `member` and `membership`.

A `member has many memberships, dependent: :destroy`, and a `membership` belongs to a `member`.

The issue is that in some situations, because `membership` belongs to many models (e.g. a `user`), there are times when I want to disassociate the `membership` from the `member` and re-associate it with a `user` record.

If it were the other way, i.e. removing a `membership` from the `member` record it is more straightforward. I would just do: `member.memberships.destroy(membership)` or `member.memberships.first.destroy` or w/e.

But....I am doing the reverse, i.e. I want to keep the `membership` record, but want to remove the association with the `member`.

So I would want to do something like `membership.member.destroy`, without it deleting either of the records. Once I delete the `member` record, it automatically deletes the associated `membership` records because of the `dependent: :destroy`.

Comment: "without deleting either of the records" - ehm, just set `member_id` to nil and be done with it?

Comment: That was my first choice, but is it really that simple? I was under the impression I had to do more for the association?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a good time to look at polymorphic associations. Also I think if you use delete instead of destroy it will not trigger the dependent destroy action on the association.

Comment: That's waaay too complicated for what I want to do. Sergio's comment is perfect. Just simply setting the `member_id` to nil works fine for what I want.